# ActionSheetPicker replacement for ios 8

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

In iOS 7 have been using [ActionSheetPicker](https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker) to let the user to select a choice and it has been working great until I installed Xcode beta 2 and ran my project in iOS 8. Is there a way to do this in iOS 8?

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLDco.jpg

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I asked a legitimate questions which looks like will not get answered. I did a little more research and it will just be easier to create a picker view and hide/show as needed.

Comment: check out this question and answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330152/showing-a-uipickerview-with-uiactionsheet-in-ios8-not-working

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana, why the upvote?

Answer (score 9):

There is a fork [ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) which has been updated to work for iOS 8.

Comment: Welcome. Feel free to open an issue if you still need help. it supports ios 13 as well

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and couldn't find a solution.

I ended up using a `UIViewController` instead of `UIActionSheet`. I added the `UIPickerView` as a subView to the viewController's view and presented in modally.