# Showing a UIPickerView with UIActionSheet in iOS8 not working

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller, actionsheetpicker

Showing a `UIPickerView` with `UIActionSheet` in **iOS8** not working

The code works in **iOS7**, however it is not working in **iOS8**. I'm sure it is because UIActionSheet is deprecated in **iOS8** and Apple recommends to use `UIAlertController`.

However, how to do it in **iOS8**? I should use `UIAlertController`?

**iOS7**:
[image]

**iOS8**:
[image]

**EDIT:**

[My GitHub project solving the problem.](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/Picker-iOS8)

Comment: My project solving the problem: https://github.com/GabrielMassana/Picker-iOS8

Comment: You can check my solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366437/add-uipickerview-in-uiactionsheet-from-ios-8-not-working/26095499#26095499

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana please, review my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26731722/1698467 is seems, that is what you are looking for!

Comment: Adding a UIPickerView to UIAllertController ActionSheet still works the same way even in iOS 9.3.1 without any logical changes. The code from my example is from one of my projects and was written before 2 years (in the beginning of Swift) and works like a charm. You, probably, have some code "aberrations" which causes the malfunctioning of the Action Sheet view and its subviews. Take a look at my example. It could help you in future projects.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545982/is-there-any-way-to-add-uipickerview-into-uialertcontroller-alert-or-actionshee/27122847#27122847

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the reference for UIActionSheet:

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:.

My guess is your seeing exactly why.

The reference for UIAlertController doesn't have a similar disclaimer, but looking at its interface, my guess is Apple will add it before release.

My recommendation would be to just create a small view containing your picker and buttons and show and hide it as needed.  It's not that hard to do and your not pushing interfaces beyond their intended uses.

Comment: I uploaed my example with  `UIView.animateWithDuration(duration: animations:, completion:)`. It works perfectly.

Comment: The question of whether we will be able to subclass `UIAlertController` has been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017657/subclassing-uialertcontroller because it would be an interesting (And a surprising) move if Apple do allow us to subclass it. It maybe worth following because I will be providing an update when iOS8 is officially released.

Answer (score 4):

I write the time picker by my self instead UIActionSheet in iOS8:

```
date = [NSDate date];

timePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];
timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
timePicker.hidden = NO;
timePicker.date = date;

displayFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[displayFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[displayFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM月dd日 EEE HH:mm"];

formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

startDisplayTimeString = [displayFormatter stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
startTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:timePicker.date];

NSTimeInterval interval = 24*60*60*1;
NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval];
endDisplayTimeString = [displayFormatter stringFromDate:endDate];
endTimeString = [formatter stringFromDate:endDate];

[_startTimeLabel setText:startDisplayTimeString];
[_endTimeLabel setText:endDisplayTimeString];

[pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];
pickerToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelBtnPressed:)];

[cancelBtn setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:68.0/255.0 blue:142.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *titleButton;

float pickerMarginHeight = 168;


titleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target: nil action: nil];

[titleButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:68.0/255.0 blue:142.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                     nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(setTimePicker)];

[doneBtn setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:68.0/255.0 blue:142.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                 nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSArray *itemArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:cancelBtn, flexSpace, titleButton, flexSpace, doneBtn, nil];

[pickerToolbar setItems:itemArray animated:YES];

if(iPad){

    [pickerToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [popoverView addSubview:timePicker];
    [popoverView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, pickerMarginHeight, 320, 216) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}else{

    timeBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-300, 320, 246)];
    [timeBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:240/255.0 blue:240/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    [timeBackgroundView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [timeBackgroundView addSubview:timePicker];

    [self.view addSubview:timeBackgroundView];}
```

Answer (score 3):

UIActionSheet is depricated in **iOS8**. Use **UIAlertController** for **iOS8 or later**

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                            message:@"This is an action shhet."
                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* cameraAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Take A Photo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

UIAlertAction* galleryAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"From Gallery" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

UIAlertAction * defaultAct = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

[alert addAction:cameraAction];
[alert addAction:galleryAction];
[alert addAction:defaultAct];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Ref : [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController)

Example : https://github.com/KiritVaghela/UIAlertController

Comment: This probably works fine, but it doesn't use a `UIPickerView`, which is what was requested.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this action sheet simulation:

```
@interface UIViewController (ActionSheetSimulation)

-(UIView*) actionSheetSimulationWithPickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView withToolbar: (UIToolbar*)pickerToolbar;
-(void)dismissActionSheetSimulation:(UIView*)actionSheetSimulation;

@end


#import "UIViewController+ActionSheetSimulation.h"

@implementation UIViewController (ActionSheetSimulation)

-(UIView *)actionSheetSimulationWithPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView withToolbar:(UIToolbar *)pickerToolbar {

    UIView* simulatedActionSheetView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                                0,
                                                                                UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width,
                                                                                UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height)];
    [simulatedActionSheetView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    CGFloat pickerViewYpositionHidden = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height + pickerToolbar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat pickerViewYposition = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height -
        pickerView.frame.size.height +
        UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarFrame.size.height;
    [pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(pickerView.frame.origin.x,
                                pickerViewYpositionHidden,
                                pickerView.frame.size.width,
                                pickerView.frame.size.height)];
    [pickerToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(pickerToolbar.frame.origin.x,
                                   pickerViewYpositionHidden,
                                   pickerToolbar.frame.size.width,
                                   pickerToolbar.frame.size.height)];
    pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [simulatedActionSheetView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [simulatedActionSheetView addSubview:pickerView];

    [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow?UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow:UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows[0]
                                                                            addSubview:simulatedActionSheetView];
    [simulatedActionSheetView.superview bringSubviewToFront:simulatedActionSheetView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                 animations:^{
                         [simulatedActionSheetView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
                         [self.view setTintAdjustmentMode:UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed];
                         [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintAdjustmentMode:UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed];
                         [pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(pickerView.frame.origin.x,
                                                     pickerViewYposition,
                                                     pickerView.frame.size.width,
                                                     pickerView.frame.size.height)];
                         [pickerToolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(pickerToolbar.frame.origin.x,
                                                        pickerViewYposition,
                                                        pickerToolbar.frame.size.width,
                                                        pickerToolbar.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    return simulatedActionSheetView;
}

-(void)dismissActionSheetSimulation:(UIView*)actionSheetSimulation {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                 animations:^{
                         [actionSheetSimulation setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                         [self.view setTintAdjustmentMode:UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal];
                         [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintAdjustmentMode:UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal];
                         [actionSheetSimulation.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                             UIView* v = (UIView*)obj;
                             [v setFrame:CGRectMake(v.frame.origin.x,
                                                UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height,
                                                v.frame.size.width,
                                                v.frame.size.height)];
                         }];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [actionSheetSimulation removeFromSuperview];
                     }];

}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks Bulky_ooti.  Your solution works for me but with one slight modification.  I have to add the pickerView first as a subview and then add the pickerToolbar afterwards as a subview.  Otherwise, the pickerToolbar is not active

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue and solved it by this way it will work in all ios version

In ios 8 apple has changed so many things i here faced one problem in my own project so , i just want to provide the solution in replacement of `UIActionsheet`.

in ios 8 `UIActionsheet` deprecated as well its delegate methods also deprecated. Instead of that `UIAlertController` with prefferedstyle
`UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`  is used. you can check this thread as well:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html

This example will work both in ios 8 and previous version of it.

in .h file declare this variable

```
@interface demoProfileForBuyer{
 UIActionSheet *ac_sheet_fordate;
 UIToolbar *pickerToolBar_fordate;

 UIDatePicker *optionPickerDate;
 UIAlertController *alertController;
}
```

in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    pickerToolBar_fordate = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-8, 0, 320, 44)];

    pickerToolBar_fordate.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    [pickerToolBar_fordate sizeToFit];

    NSMutableArray *barItemsDate = [[NSMutableArray allkioc] init];


    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpaceDate = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItemsDate addObject:flexSpaceDate];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtnDate = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerViewDoneBirthday)];
    [barItemsDate addObject:doneBtnDate];

    [pickerToolBar_fordate setItems:barItemsDate animated:YES];

    optionPickerDate = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-8, 44, 320, 200)];


    optionPickerDate.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [optionPickerDate setMaximumDate: [NSDate date]];
    optionPickerDate.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    optionPickerDate.hidden = NO;
    optionPickerDate.date = [NSDate date];
    optionPickerDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if(IS_IOS_8){

        alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

        UIAlertAction *alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:alertAction];
        [alertController addAction:alertAction];
        [alertController addAction:alertAction];
        [alertController addAction:alertAction];        
        [alertController.view addSubview:pickerToolBar_fordate];
        [alertController.view addSubview:optionPickerDate];        
    } else {
    ac_sheet_fordate = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"test"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"dev",@"dev", nil];
    [ac_sheet_fordate setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque];
    [ac_sheet_fordate setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [ac_sheet_fordate addSubview:pickerToolBar_fordate];
    [ac_sheet_fordate addSubview:optionPickerDate];
    }
    }

// when date picker open 

   - (IBAction)showBirthdayPicker:(id)sender{
    //    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -220, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    UIButton *btnsender = sender;
    //[ac_sheet_fordate showInView:self.view];
    self.scrForEditProfile.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
    if(IS_IOS_8){
            popover = alertController.popoverPresentationController;
            if (popover)
            {
                popover.sourceView = sender;
                popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, btnsender.bounds.origin.y, btnsender.bounds.size.width, btnsender.bounds.size.height);

                popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
            }
                [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
    if(IS_IOS_7){
        [ac_sheet_fordate showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
        ac_sheet_fordate.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-ac_sheet_fordate.frame.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, ac_sheet_fordate.frame.size.height);
    }
    else{
        [ac_sheet_fordate showInView:self.view];
    }
    }
    if(IS_IOS_7==FALSE && IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568==FALSE){
        [self.scrForEditProfile scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.txtDOB.frame.origin.x, self.txtDOB.frame.origin.y + 200, self.txtDOB.frame.size.width, self.txtDOB.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
    }
    else{
        [self.scrForEditProfile scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.txtDOB.frame.origin.x, self.txtDOB.frame.origin.y +300, self.txtDOB.frame.size.width, self.txtDOB.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
    }

}

// when date picker open user tap on done button

- (IBAction)pickerViewDoneBirthday{

    if(IS_IOS_8){
        [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    } else {
        [ac_sheet_fordate dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    }

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    birthday_date = optionPickerDate.date;
    [self.btnShowDatePicker setTitle:[formatter stringFromDate:optionPickerDate.date] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnShowDatePicker setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnShowDatePicker setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    self.scrForEditProfile.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320 , 700);
    [self.scrForEditProfile scrollsToTop];

}
```

you can check my blog also,
http://ioscodesample.blogspot.in/2014/10/ios-8-changes-for-actionsheet.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**swift 5**

You can use an `UIAlertController` to do this.

```
@IBAction func btnActionDate(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 16.0, height: 150))
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self

//        let message = "\n\n\n\n\n\n"
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title of Action Sheet", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
        alert.isModalInPopover = true

        picker.reloadAllComponents()

        //Add the picker to the alert controller
        alert.view.addSubview(picker)

        // For setting height of Action sheet
        let height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alert.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 350)
        alert.view.addConstraint(height)


        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let fetchedObj = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        })
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Set the delegates & data source of pickerView like this

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
```

set the delegate & datasource functions

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

            return arrayMonthData.count

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

            return arrayMonthData[row]

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return self.view.frame.size.width - 16.0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 36.0
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                               message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                                               preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"确认" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [weakSelf pickActionSheetFinishAction];
}];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController.view addSubview:self.topicPickView];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you, showing a UIPickerView with UIActionSheet is not working in iOS 8. Because UIActionSheet is deprecated and Apple recommends to use UIAlertController. So we should round to wind.

I wrote some code to resolve my case. I hope it can help you.

```
#define CONTENT_HEIGHT 478

- (void)initSheetWithWidth:(CGFloat)aWidth
{
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        UIAlertController *sheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"hack space" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
        [sheet.view setBounds:CGRectMake(7, 0, aWidth, CONTENT_HEIGHT)]; // Kinda hacky
        self.sheet = sheet;
    } else {
        UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
        self.sheet = sheet;
    }

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, aWidth, CONTENT_HEIGHT)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, aWidth, 0)];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [toolbar sizeToFit];

    [toolbar setItems:@[
                        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(pickerSheetCancel)],
                        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerSheetDone)]
                        ]];

    UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, toolbar.bounds.size.height, aWidth, 0)];


    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        UIAlertController *sheet = self.sheet;
        [view addSubview:toolbar];
        [view addSubview:picker];
        [sheet.view addSubview:view];
    } else {
        UIActionSheet *sheet = self.sheet;
        [sheet addSubview:toolbar];
        [sheet addSubview:picker];
    }

    self.picker = picker;
}

- (void)showWithDate:(NSDate*)date {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        // Reload and select first item
        [self.picker setDate:date];

        [self.parentViewController presentViewController:self.sheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        UIActionSheet *sheet = self.sheet;
        [self.sheet showInView:self.containerView];

        // XXX: Kinda hacky, but seems to be the only way to make it display correctly.
        [self.sheet
         setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                              self.containerView.frame.size.width,
                              sheet.frame.size.height - CONTENT_HEIGHT)];

        // Reload and select first item
        [self.picker setDate:date];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            [self.sheet
             setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                  self.containerView.frame.size.width,
                                  sheet.frame.size.height)];
        }];
    }
}
```

I think it's all to fix this issue.
Happy coding!

Comment: what is self.sheet and self.picker?

Comment: @Arunakumari, there're id object and UIPickerView.
..property (nonatomic, strong) id sheet;
..property (nonatomic, strong) UIPickerView *picker;

Comment: I think we should not modify view of UIAlertViewController. Apple documentation says its private. "The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali you's right, this way's not recommended