# The message in UIAlertController is too long to display, how can I do?

Tags: ios8, uialertcontroller

I will show a disclaimer after the user login, but it seems the message of disclaimer is too long that the UIAlertController can show the whole text, can't show the title, can't scroll the message, didn't show the action button.
Is there someone has this situation, and how did you fix this?

Now, I add UITextView as a subview to show message.How to set the frame of UIAlertController is a problem, and I solve this by setting message in UIAlertController.
Hope apple can fix it in future.

Comment: suggestion is write it in lable put it in scroll view and add scrollview into UIAlertController's view.

Comment: I add a UITextView to show the Message, the trouble I got is how to set the frame of UIAlertController. I set the frame by set message to UIAlertController to get a suitable size.

Comment: UIAlertController is view controllers you can create sub class it, and set it's view size.

Comment: I my case i do it like this to increase frame, add extra \n, but i suggest to  create subclass http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652101/please-wait-dialog-in-ios8/25671652#25671652

Comment: I want to use the UIAlertAction, add extern string as message is more useful.