# How to add date picker to UIAlertController(UIAlertView) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have an application in which I need to display a popup to pick a date and write that date back to the view controller.

I have searched online a lot but wasn't successful in finding out a relevant solution.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated in the iOS 8 SDK.  Do you mean a `UIAlertController`?  If so, this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545982/is-there-any-way-to-add-uipickerview-into-uialertcontroller-alert-or-actionshee

Comment: @JAL Yes I meant UIAlertController. The link you have given is not about Swift (I mean the answers users gave for the question). I don't know Objective-C, I started with Swift so it's kind of difficult for me to convert that code to Swift.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do not use any kind of UIAlertView or UIAlertController. Make your *own* view and pop it up (using, probably, a presented view controller). The view can be small, like an date picker, and you can put a shadow view behind it, like an alert does.

Comment: This example will get you started: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 It doesn't involve a date picker, but it shows how to turn _any_ view into something that looks and acts like an alert.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Code :

```
- (id)initWithDatePicker:(NSString*)title parentView:(UIView*)parentView {
 self = [super init];

 if (self) {
     datePickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
     datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
     if (IS_IOS8_AND_UP) {
         alertViewController = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:EMPTY_STRING
                                message:title
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
         UIView* aboveBlurLayer = alertViewController.view.subviews[0];
         [aboveBlurLayer addSubview:datePickerView];
         [aboveBlurLayer setWidth:SCREEN_WIDTH - 16];
         [datePickerView setWidth:SCREEN_WIDTH - 16];
         [alertViewController.view setWidth:SCREEN_WIDTH - 16];
         [alertViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

         UIAlertAction* alertAction =
         [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:EMPTY_STRING
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:nil];
         [alertViewController addAction:alertAction];
         [alertViewController addAction:alertAction];
         [alertViewController addAction:alertAction];
         [alertViewController addAction:alertAction];

         [datePickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
         [aboveBlurLayer addSubview:datePickerView];
     } else {
         actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

         [actionSheet addSubview:datePickerView];
     }

     [self addToolBar];
     isDatePicker = YES;
     parent = parentView;
 }   
  return self; 
}
```

On Tool bar I have two buttons Done and Cancel 
On Done i send back a call via delegate with selected date and on cancel I dismiss. 
This code is for both iOS 7 and iOS 8