# xcode ios NSRangeException on creating subviews

Tags: ios8, uipickerview, uiactionsheet, subviews

**how do I change the code below to fix the pickerView being depreciated?**

This code has worked well before and did the job. I havent needed to compile for a while and when I was fixing another problem I bumped into this NSRangeException when it hits the subview.  The code used to work with a previous version of IOS. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

First throw call stack:... etc etc

After more reading I find that the pickerView is depreciated.

Never will understand why Apple can just change code!

```
-(void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {

    switch ([actionSheet tag] ) {
        case 1://date

        {    
            NSDate *d;

            UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 116)];

            [pickerView setTag:100+[actionSheet  tag]];

            [pickerView setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

            if( DefDate == @"" || DefDate == Nil ) DefDate = [fun0 GetCurrentDate];

            d = [fun0 GetDatefromString:DefDate];

            [pickerView setDate:d animated:YES];

            [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

            [pickerView release];

            NSArray *subViews = [actionSheet subviews];


**// Line below is where is where it dumps:**

            [[subViews objectAtIndex: SelectButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 266, 280, 46)]; 
            [[subViews objectAtIndex:CancelButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 317, 280, 46)];



        }

            break; 

    }


}




- (IBAction)btnDate:(id)sender {



    UIActionSheet *asheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 

                             initWithTitle:@"Pick the date of your meal" 
                             delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:@""
                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                             otherButtonTitles:@"Select"
                             , nil];

    [asheet setTag:1];
    [asheet showInView:[self.view superview]]; 

    [asheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 383)];
    [asheet release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it with iOS 8.0 (and running on XCode6.1) and above, and your code and `UIActionSheet` both looks nice.

It can compile, run and showing me the output.

Here's what I get.

[image]

**Update:**

From iOS 8.0 and above, `UIActionSheet` is depreciated. Also its stop supporting add subviews too. This means device with iOS 8.0 and above will not show you `UIDatePicker` as subview of it. If notice, nightmare is not the error line you've specified below the comment but its not showing data picker any more inside action sheet.

From Documentation,

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add
>   views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more
>   customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create
>   your own and present it modally with
>   presentViewController:animated:completion:.

IMHO,

1. You should upgrade your app and code to start supporting from iOS 8.0 only. `UIActionSheet` will be replace by `UIAlertController`. [**Suggested**]
2. If you wish to support back iOS 8 then you've to use a third party action sheet which you can use in place of `UIActionSheet` in all iOS versions. Here's the one, https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0 [**Good Alternative**]
3. If you don't want to use third party and still wants to support all iOS versions, then you can runtime check for iOS versions and based on that you can either show `UIActionSheet` and `UIAlertController`. [**Not Recommended**]

Few links which may help you.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/

[Add UIPickerView in UIActionSheet from IOS 8 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366437/add-uipickerview-in-uiactionsheet-from-ios-8-not-working/26095499#26095499)

[Showing a UIPickerView with UIActionSheet in iOS8 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330152/showing-a-uipickerview-with-uiactionsheet-in-ios8-not-working)

Comment: thank you for the example. Looking further I realized that its actually further along when it gets the exception.  see the new code I added above. thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Action Sheet Picker worked great as I was able to chat directly with the developer to get going. I guess It took me a little while to get going understanding it as I dont program in IOS every day, but once I did its awesome! Thank you to Hemang above for all the suggestions!

[ACTION SHEET PICKER](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0)