# How can i make my own view and pop it up ? i want to make a language picker when taped on button click alert which contain 7 languages

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I want to input in it a 7 languages that the user pick then click OK or Cancel to set it on a label. Sorry for asking a lot but I couldn't find any good answers. All I found was about datepicker i want to do the same page this guy using ([Showing a UIPickerView with UIActionSheet in iOS8 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330152/showing-a-uipickerview-with-uiactionsheet-in-ios8-not-working)) can u help me plz with any info thanks in advance

Comment: Check this tutorial of how to do this http://sourcefreeze.com/ios-uipickerview-example-using-swift/

Comment: what i need is a picker in  something like an alert than when u click it it opens   like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330152/showing-a-uipickerview-with-uiactionsheet-in-ios8-not-working

Comment: at first a searched on how to make  picker in alert but then i found this : Do not use any kind of UIAlertView or UIAlertController. Make your own view and pop it up (using, probably, a presented view controller). The view can be small, like an date picker, and you can put a shadow view behind it, like an alert does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the code I used to solve my problem plus the autocomplete for anyone having the same problem as me.
Here is the solution for datepicker with (done,cancel) buttons

```
 var picker = UIPickerView() 
 var autocompleteUrls = [String]()

    
  
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     
    // The Auto Compelete Delegates
    DatePickerTextOutLet.delegate = self
    NationalityOutLet.delegate = self
      AutoComTable.delegate = self
      AutoComTable.dataSource = self
      AutoComTable.scrollEnabled = true
      AutoComTable.hidden = true
  } // ViewdidLoad
///////////////////////////////////Language picker


func PickerSensei(textField:UITextField){
    let picker: UIPickerView
    picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 200))
    picker.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    
    
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self
    
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 226/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    //        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "CancelPicker")
    
    
    toolBar.setItems([  spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    
    
    textField.inputView = picker
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
func donePicker() {
    PickerSensei(FirstnameoutLet)
    if ((FirstnameoutLet.text?.characters.count) < 1 ){
        FirstnameoutLet.text = "Arabic"
        
    }
    FirstnameoutLet.resignFirstResponder()
    
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: PreferedLanguagesResult[row], attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
    return attributedString
}

   func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return  1
    
}

   // returns the # of rows in each component..
   func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return PreferedLanguagesResult.count
}
     func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
     FirstnameoutLet.text = String(PreferedLanguagesResult[row])
    //        FirstnameoutLet.endEditing(true)
}
  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return self.PreferedLanguagesResult[row]
}

  //////////////////////// end of Langauge picker
 

     //////// Date Picker

   @IBAction func DatePickeractionButton(sender: AnyObject) {

}
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    DatePickerTextOutLet.inputView = datePicker
   // datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    BirthDate = DatePickerTextOutLet.text!
    
    
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 216/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    datePicker.setValue(UIColor.redColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    
    // Adds the buttons
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "doneClick")
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "cancelClick")
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    
    // Adds the toolbar to the view
    DatePickerTextOutLet.inputView = datePicker
    DatePickerTextOutLet.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
   //        print(BirthDate)
    
  }
func doneClick() {
    print(datePicker.date.age)
    if ((datePicker.date.age) >= 9460800 && (datePicker.date.age) <= 42048000 ){
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    DatePickerTextOutLet.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    DatePickerTextOutLet.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if ((datePicker.date.age) <= 9460800 ){
         alertWithTitle("Go Home", message: "You are To young my Child", ViewController: self, toFocus: DatePickerTextOutLet)
    } //younger than 18 Years Old
    else if ((datePicker.date.age) >= 42048000 ){
        alertWithTitle("Sorry Sir", message: "You are to Old for This Shit", ViewController: self, toFocus: DatePickerTextOutLet)

      }// older than 80 Years Old
  }

   func cancelClick() {
    DatePickerTextOutLet.resignFirstResponder()
   }

    ///////// Date Picker End

    /////////////////// that as for the picker now for the auto complete :-
       
              //////////////////////// The Begining of Auto Compelete

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    AutoComTable!.hidden = false
    
    let text = NationalityOutLet.text ?? ""
    
    let substring = ( text as NSString  ).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string )
    
    searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring)
    return true
}
func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String)
{
    autocompleteUrls.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    // print(substring)
    
    for curString in NationalityIDResults
    {
        //   print(curString)
        let myString: NSString! = curString as! NSString
        let substringRange: NSRange! = myString.rangeOfString(substring)
        if (substringRange.location == 0)
        {
            autocompleteUrls.append(String(curString))
        }
    }
    
    AutoComTable.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return autocompleteUrls.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let autoCompleteRowIdentifier = "AutoCompleteRowIdentifier"
    
    
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(autoCompleteRowIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!
    //  print(cell)
    
    if let tempo1 = cell
    {
        let index = indexPath.row as Int
        cell.textLabel!.text = autocompleteUrls[index]
    } else
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: autoCompleteRowIdentifier)
    }
    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    //     var currentTextField = textField.text
    NationalityOutLet.text = selectedCell.textLabel!.text
    AutoComTable.hidden = true
    
}

////////////////////////////////////////// The End of Auto Compelete
```